# Bad Requests and Timeouts

Tags: java, sockets

I want to access an arbitrary webpage using sockets (as a learning mechanism for myself). The code below does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Example
{
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
     {
          Socket socket =
               new Socket("www.google.com", 80);
          PrintWriter out =
               new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
          BufferedReader reader =
               new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

          BufferedReader stdIn =
               new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          String userInput;
          while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
               out.println("GET / HTTP/1.1 \\r\\n Host: www.google.com \\r\\n\\r\\n");
               System.out.println("echo: " + reader.readLine());
         }
     }
}
```

After trying for a couple hours I was unable to figure out what exactly I was doing wrong. All I want is Google's or some other websites homepage. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try with apache http client

Comment: The purpose is to learn standard, vanilla Java. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: The code appears fine!

Comment: What errors do you get exactly?

Comment: 400s and 408s and I/O blocking to the point I have to end the process

Comment: You should not have `\\r\\n` but `\r\n` for get to succeed (see my updated answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like the following (using sockets)

```
package com.example.webpagesocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;

public class GetWebPageUsingSockets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String urlString;

        urlString = "www.google.com";

        accessWeb(urlString);
    }

    private static void accessWeb(String urlString) {
        String host;
        String page;
        int slashLoc;

        // Set up encoding and decoding
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();

        if ((slashLoc = urlString.indexOf('/')) < 0) {
            host = urlString;
            page = "";
        } else {
            host = urlString.substring(0, slashLoc);
            page = urlString.substring(slashLoc);
        }

        System.out.println("Accessing web page demonstration");
        System.out.println("Host: '" + host + "' Page: '" + page + "'");

        SocketChannel channel = null;

        try {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
            CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(1024);

            InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, 80);
            channel = SocketChannel.open();
            channel.connect(socketAddress);

            String request = "GET " + page + " \r\n\r\n";
            channel.write(encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(request)));

            while ((channel.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                buffer.flip();
                decoder.decode(buffer, charBuffer, false);
                charBuffer.flip();
                System.out.println(charBuffer);
                buffer.clear();
                charBuffer.clear();
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (channel != null) {
                try {
                    channel.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nDone.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not so much the result, is the means to achieve the result. I'm trying to use sockets...

Comment: Redid example to use sockets (and edited question to clarify what was wanted)

Answer (score 0):

Edit : didn't notice the \ at first reading ...

It looks like you are continuously sending `"GET / HTTP/1.1 \\r\\n Host: www.google.com \\r\\n\\r\\n"` to the host (at each read). You'd better keeping it out of the loop and sent true `carriage return + line feed` and not printable chars `\ r \ n` :

```
  out.println("GET / HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");
  String userInput;
      while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
```

You only start reading after sending your `GET`, but the socket will buffer data.

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you so much for the edit. I wish I could give both of you the check mark but I had given it to him and he did a lot of work to help me out when I thought it was gg. Thanks so much, man. No really. You have no idea how long I have been working on this.